# In Slick, what import is needed to use Table[T]?

Tags: database, scala, jdbc, slick

I'm sure this is obvious, and I should be reading some manual instead of asking this questions, but I can't sort it out.

I'm following the ([*Getting Started*](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/gettingstarted.html)) manual for Slick 3.2.0. It states that I should include a dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.slick</groupId>
        <artifactId>slick_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I'm trying to replicate the very first example:

```
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database
import slick.lifted.Tag
case class BusinessRelationshipRow (
   id: Long,
   name: String,
   phone: String)


class BusinessRelationshipTable(tag: Tag) 
      extends Table[BusinessRelationshipRow]
      (tag, "BUSINESS_RELATIONSHIP") 
{

}
```

And my question is: what import do I need to use the **Table[BusinessRelationshipRow]**? I've tried a *slick.mode.Table*, but it takes no parameters.

As no one is even mentioning this problem, I guess it is trivial. Still, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the `api` for the particular database you are using. In my case it is Postgres so I have

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
```

which gives `Table` and the other types you need.

Comment: Yes, thanks! And for Oracle database it is *import slick.jdbc.OracleProfile.api._*

Comment: There are a lot of blogs about slick. This information about `import slick.jdbc.<>.api._` is not explicitly mentioned for beginners.